# Not receiving email notifications

Tags: support, notifications, email

I registered on Stack Overflow today, and answered a couple of new questions. However, I did not receive any email notifications for the posts where an update happened. I have done the preliminary checks on my side: I made sure I checked the option to get notified via email for updates. I checked my email spam folder. However, all my efforts were futile.

***Resolution :***

I am now able to receive email notifications after editing my email preferences to get notified for any new comment every 3 hours. Earlier it was set to 1 day.

Comment: No problem, welcome to Stack Overflow! Since this sounds like a support issue, I would try contacting them via http://stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: Thank you folks whoever took sometime to take care of my post. I finally got a solution and all the credit goes to the folks who directly/indirectly contributed. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now able to receive **email notifications** after editing my **email preferences** to get notified for any new comment every **3 hours**.

Earlier it was set to 1 day. The shortest interval to receive notification is three hours post an action.

Comment: Same problem here. I have never received __any kind__ of notification from stackexchange/stackoverflow ever, even though it was enabled in my profile. I'll try setting it to 3 hours too.

Comment: @fritzmg Check your spam folder once. Actually, the functionality is that if you receive and comment etc. on your post, and if you do not login for next 3 hours, then you get an email notification. Perhaps, you are logging in too frequently.

Comment: I always checked my spamfolder for any messages from stackexchange - there was never a single email when users created answers or comments to my questions and the like. I have received answers/comments to my questions after not being logged in for several days, yet there was never any notification.

Comment: @fritzmg Then it seems like a different issue. Do report it to the [Stack Overflow team](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact). Please let me know if you get any solution from them. All the best!

Comment: @fritzmg Any update?

Comment: So far no, I have set it to 3 hours and wanted to observe first, if this setting works - which it does. I'll set it back to one day and observe again.